# Refreshing a data table in android

Tags: android, auto-update

Following code is for an activity in my android application, this is still an outline of the application so it does not entail much but once the basic requirements are in placed I could go further for design.

This is my Database helper class. What it goes to the Local host, gets the data in my database and then brings it back and displays it in a listview.

```
  package com.example.parking_guide;

public class DBHelper extends ListActivity {

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static final String url_all_products = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "level1";
    private static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    private static final String KEY_VACANT = "vacancy";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray table = null;  

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        ListView yourListView = getListView();



        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */

    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("level1", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    table = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < table.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = table.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String _id = c.getString(KEY_ROWID);
                        String vacant = c.getString(KEY_VACANT);


                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(KEY_ROWID, _id);
                        map.put(KEY_VACANT, vacant);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } 
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {


            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            DBHelper.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
                                    KEY_VACANT},
                            new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.vac});
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
  }'
```

This code accomplishes fine, but my application would later require this to act as close to a real-time server as possible or at least try to be. So I'm going to need to refresh the data after few seconds (as less as five seconds perhaps) to keep the data on the screen updated. 
I've read about timers and handlers but I can't really get a grip of any of those concepts. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Change ListAdapter to BaseAdapter;
and add the
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
on ui
you can give commented code in onCreate for better performance

public class DBHelper extends ListActivity {

```
// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static final String url_all_products = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "level1";
private static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
private static final String KEY_VACANT = "vacancy";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray table = null;  

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    ListView yourListView = getListView();



    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

BaseAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    DBHelper.this, productsList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
                            KEY_VACANT},
                    new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.vac});
             updating listview
            setListAdapter(adapter);

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */

class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("level1", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                table = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < table.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = table.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String _id = c.getString(KEY_ROWID);
                    String vacant = c.getString(KEY_VACANT);


                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(KEY_ROWID, _id);
                    map.put(KEY_VACANT, vacant);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {


        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

}'

Comment: I did change my code in that exact same way but still nothing! I add, delete or change entries in my DB and the changes are not displayed in the app

Comment: i did't find where ur using DataBase in the above code dear.. are you talking about the list data

Comment: it does not so much use as it just shows the data using the list_item layout. Each row is displayed on a list_item layout one after another as they all fit into one big list. I don't know if you get what I'm saying, would you like to see a screenshot of the activity while it's running?